# bash Calculate age of person and read to csv file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a csv file with three columns that reads name,postcode,age dd/mm/yy. I would like to calculate the age of each entry from todays date and output to a fourth column of the csv file? I know awk is handy but i dont know to read and write the data from the various column and create a new one!
e.g

```
name,postcode,dob,age
Dave,ws245f,09/12/2000,13
```

I have the following input

```
`cat estimateAge.csv|awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");a (systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1;print $0","a}`'
```

and this is the output

```
Joe Bloggs,0121 545465650,01/03/1982,31
```

The output should be

```
Joe Bloggs,0121 545465650,01/03/1982,30
```

Note the age calc is incorrect as the Joe Bloggs is not yet 31 until March

Comment: Have you got any other homework you'd like us to do? Seriously, though.. what have you tried? please read the about pages of this site before posting a question like this...

Comment: +1 this is a good question, though OP did/may not put enough effort in. dateDiff and ceiling calculation with awk..interesting topics

Comment: What is up with so many people posting sample input but not the expected output from that input? Is there a FAQ somewhere we can point people to?

Comment: @EdMorton I think the codes block in question is output. the 13 (last field) should be calculated and appended to each line. well with the dob (date of birth).  In his problem description, he made mistake that field "age" should not be in input. it seems that I was the OP . ^_^

Comment: What i am looking for is to compare the DOB to the current sysytem date and calculate the age in the final column. One method would be to use Epoch time and convert both the inputs into seconds and then convert them back? But i may still need a loop to read the all the value in the column and perform the calculation?What i am looking for is to compare the DOB to the current sysytem date and calculate

Comment: @TrickyDicky I think you should rephrase your question, think about you were the one who want to answer it, if you read it, can you get idea what the OP wanted? Also you commented on my answer, "It not quite working." why? what error msg did you have? what was not working? if you want to gain further help/support, you should provide enough information.  anyway, make your question complete, input example, expected output, clear requirement description etc. good luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question has been closed, but you can improve it and possibly have it re-opened by editing your question. Improvements generally include posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Has been edited with examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the core part of this problem is not adding the new age field to the end. but the age calculation.

try this:

```
awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");a=(systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1;print $0","a}' file
```

well maybe I should not put them into one line:

```
awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");
              a=(systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);
              a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1;print $0","a}' file
```

test with your example data:

```
kent$  echo "Dave,ws245f,09/12/2000"|awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");a=(systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1;print $0","a}' 
Dave,ws245f,09/12/2000,13
```

as you can see, I didn't check the title line, a `NR>1` check could easily skip the title. You could DIY.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the solution i have tested it with my CSV file

Comment: +1 @Kent very nearly correct i edited the post thanks!