# How to calculate age from system date using AWK>

Tags: bash, shell, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash Calculate age of person and read to csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348843/bash-calculate-age-of-person-and-read-to-csv-file)

I am calculating the age of particpant from the date of birth in a CSV file. I am using this code and i am comparing the DOB to the current system time and calculate age:

```
echo "Dave,ws245f,09/12/1982"|awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");a=(systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1;print $0","a}'
```

And the output is

```
Dave,ws245f,09/12/1982,31
```

Desired Output

```
Dave,ws245f,09/12/1982,30
```

Note: the user is not 30 until December 12th dd/mm/yyyy so the calucaltion is wrong. Please help!

Comment: Exact duplicate, same author :|

Comment: Of course, `09/12/1982` is actually September 12th (or December 9th for those who prefer DD/MM over MM/DD), so I'm not sure where December 12th comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "Dave,ws245f,09/12/1982"|awk -F'/|,' '{b=mktime($5" "$4" "$3" 00 00 00 00");a=(systime()-b)/(365*24*60*60);a+=a<0?-0.5:0.5;a=int(a);print $0","a}'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a million David works like a dream!!

Comment: Can you kindly explain how you got it working please David

Comment: @TrickyDicky The only thing I changed was this:  `a+=a<0?-0.5:0.5;a=int(a)`.  This simply says that if a is negative, then subtract 0.5, otherwise, add 0.5, then cast the result to an int. When you cast a float to an int, you are simply truncating the number, rather than rounding it.  So, for a positive number, if you add 0.5 to the float before casting it to an int, then you will always get proper rounding to the nearest whole integer.  You can prove this to yourself by adding  0.5 to various floating point values, then truncating the result.

Answer (score 1):

what about replacing `a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)+1` by `a=a==int(a)?a:int(a)` ? if you have 0.5 year, you don't have 1 but 0 year (and 6 months)

which means you could just say: `a=int(a)`